# code coverage with emma / sonar / jacoco

Tags: gwt, sonarqube, emma, jacoco

We measure the code coverage in a gwt project with emma, as described here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingCoverage.html

This works and I get the html report, the `emma.em` and the `emma.ec` file.

On sonar I have only jacoco as coverage recording, which doesn't work for gwt unit tests.
But there is the possibility to import jacoco.exec files: `sonar.jacoco.reportPath`

How can I convert now the `emma.em` and/or the `emma.ec` file to the jacoco.exec format?
Or is it possible to generate `jacoco.exec` files directly from emma?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem? We have the same issue, only with Android, Ant and Jenkins builds.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get coverage report with Sonar Emma plugin.
Please follow below link.
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Emma+Plugin

Comment: This plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'gwt'//https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin
apply plugin: "jacoco"
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"

}
test{

    jacoco {

          includes= ["test.*"]//filter
          classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/classes/main")


    }

}
```